# *** VALIDATE xxx *** in dmesg meaning?

Tags: linux-mint, dmesg

I can see these 4 VALIDATE lines in my `dmesg` protocol:

```
$ \dmesg | grep VALIDATE
[    0.176538] *** VALIDATE proc ***
[    0.176572] *** VALIDATE cgroup1 ***
[    0.176574] *** VALIDATE cgroup2 ***
[    0.374729] *** VALIDATE hugetlbfs ***
```

Can anyone tell me what the nature of them is? Is it harmless, is it maybe a warning of some kind?

My kernel is version: 5.3.0-24-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me share a bit of my searching:

The line had been there until [v5.6](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/7111951b8d4973bda27ff663f2cf18b663d15b48/fs/fs_parser.c#L371) and then deleted after [this](https://www.spinics.net/lists/kernel/msg3433336.html) discussion. Apparently, according to the discussion, the message is perfectly normal and does not mean anything significant.